# Passing an array to a function is extremely slow

Tags: arrays, performance, powershell

I have written a PowerShell script that requires passing large byte arrays between functions. The script runs **extremely** slowly. The sample code below reproduces the problem. It simply passes a 10 MiB array into a function that does nothing (other than log a message), and measures how long the call takes.

```
function do-nothing
{
    param($foo)
    Write-Verbose -Verbose "in the function"
}

$tenMiB = 10 * 1024 * 1024
$myFoo = New-Object byte[] $tenMiB

Write-Verbose -Verbose "about to do call a function that does nothing..."
$elapsed = Measure-Command -Expression { do-nothing -foo $myFoo }
Write-Verbose -Verbose "doing nothing took $($elapsed.TotalMilliseconds) milliseconds"
```

I expect this to take a few milliseconds. On my home PC it takes nearly 3000 ms and runs a CPU core at 100%. I get the same result with PowerShell 4 and PowerShell 5 (pre-production version). The same thing happens with my work PC and servers. However, one colleague gets the expected result - a few milliseconds to execute, minimal CPU usage.

The execution time is roughly proportional to the size of the array, which makes no sense to me. The size of the array should not matter.

I wondered if the array was somehow being copied. I do not think this is the case because calling `GetHashCode()` on the array returns the same value inside and outside of the function.

If the array is wrapped in a `PSCustomObject`, and the wrapper is passed to the function, then the code performs as expected. This is a bit ugly as a workaround, and I'd rather understand what is going on before resorting to it.

Can anyone explain this seemingly weird behaviour please?

Comment: I have no answer but in Powershell version 4 on my machine your code never takes more than 2.3 milliseconds to execute and rarely takes more than 1.8, based on 20 consecutive executions.

Comment: Same here, also v4.0.

Comment: I was able to reproduce long execution times on 2 different machines. Windows 8.1 with PowerShell 4.0 and 2012 R2 with PowerShell 5 production preview. The workstation took about 3.5 seconds, the server (a VM) took over 7 seconds.

Comment: @briantist Does problem reproduced if you use reference type array like `object[]` instead of `byte[]`?

Comment: @PetSerAl good question. The machines I tried that are slow are both at work. I'll have to try that tomorrow. For reference (ha) I did try explicitly pass the byte array with `[ref]` and there was no change, but I don't know if that was enough of a test.

Comment: @PetSerAl I tried your suggestion. On my work PC the time reduced from ~3000ms to ~100ms and on a server it reduced from ~5500ms to ~150ms. Much better, but still two orders of magnitude slower than I would expect

Comment: @PetSerAl this is interesting, see my answer edits. On one machine `object[]` is much faster than `byte[]`, on the other it's much slower.

Comment: On Win10/v5.0, a considerable amount of time seems to be spent generating values to populate the array prior to parameter binding

Answer (score 4):

I'm posting this as a community wiki, intended to be a place where we can post our individual environments and test results, since there seems to be some trouble reproducing. Maybe we can figure out the conditions that cause this, and from there determine why it's slow in the instances that it is. Formatting suggestions / changes welcome.

---

## [briantist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3905079/briantist)

#### Workstation

> - HW (i7)
> - Windows 8.1
> - PowerShell 4.0
> - ISE and Console
> - Domain joined
> - **`byte[]` Result: ~3,500ms**
> - **`object[]` Result: ~6,500ms**

#### Server VM

> - VM (VMware ESXi)
> - Windows 2012 R2
> - PowerShell 5.0.10514.6 (Production Preview)
> - ISE
> - Domain joined
> - **`byte[]` Result: > 7,000ms**
> - **`object[]` Result: ~100ms**

#### Home Workstation

> - HW (i5)
> - Windows 10 build 1511
> - PowerShell 5
> - ISE and Console
> - Workgroup (No AD)
> - **Result: 4-6ms first run, < 2ms subsequent runs**

---

## [emanresu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5066540/emanresu)

> - PowerShell 4
> - **Result: 1.8 - 2.4ms**

---

## [Bacon Bits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/696808/bacon-bits)

#### Workstation

> - Windows 7 x64 SP1
> - Domain joined
> - PowerShell 4
> - **Result: 100 executions, average of 1.16ms, min 0.67ms, max 13.88ms, 1.39ms stddev**

#### VM (ESXi)

> - Windows Server 2012 R2
> - Domain joined
> - PowerShell 4
> - **Result: 10 executions, average of 4221ms, min 4173ms, max 4302ms, 38.54ms stddev**

---

## [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers)

#### VM (VirtualBox)

> - Windows 2012 R2 (vanilla install)
>
>   - PowerShell 4
>       CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.34014
>       BuildVersion: 6.3.9600.16394
>   - **Result: ~7.5ms**
> - Windows 2012 R2 (same VM, fully patched)
>
>   - PowerShell 4
>       CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.34209
>       BuildVersion: 6.3.9600.17400
>   - **Result: ~4000ms**

Further investigation revealed that the issue was introduced by the November 2014 update rollup ([MSKB 3000850](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/3000850)). Not sure which of the collected hotfixes is the actual culprit, though.

---

## [beatcracker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4424236/beatcracker)

#### Desktop

> - HW: Q6600@3.1 GHz/8GB RAM
> - Windows Server 2012
> - Workgroup (No AD)
> - PowerShell 5 (5.0.10018.0)
> - ISE and Console
> - **Result: ~5000ms**

#### Laptop

> - HW: i3@2.5 GHz/4GB RAM
> - Windows 8.1
> - Domain-joined PC
> - PowerShell 4
> - ISE and Console
> - **Result: ~6000ms**

---

## [David Brabant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/311712/david-brabant)

> - PowerShell 5
> - Windows 10
> - **Result: < 7 ms**

---

## [sodawillow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3677139/sodawillow)

> - HW (i5)
> - Windows 8.1
> - Workgroup (No AD)
> - PowerShell 5.0.10514.6
> - ISE
> - **Result: > 3500 ms**

---

## [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen)

#### Home laptop

> - HW (i7-2620M)
> - Windows 10 (build 10240)
> - PowerShell 5.0
> - ISE and Console
> - **`byte[]` Result: ~5,350ms**
> - **`object[]` Result: ~8,500ms**
> - **`int[]` Result: ~9,700ms**

---

Comment: After updating my previously unpatched playground VM execution times went from roughly 7 to about 4000 ms, so it seems like the behavior was introduced by a hotfix.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers do you know which windows update or hotfix it was?

Comment: The issue seems to be caused by one of the hotfixes from the November 2014 update rollup ([MSKB 3000850](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/3000850)).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [stack traces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34335099) posted by @Ansgar Wiechers, I was able to reproduce this behavior on my PC (Windows 10 build 1511, PowerShell 5.0.10586.0) with following code:

```
$Module = New-Module {
    function do-nothing
    {
        param($foo)
        Write-Verbose -Verbose "in the function"
    }
}
$Module.LogPipelineExecutionDetails = $true

$myFoo = New-Object byte[] 10mb

Write-Verbose -Verbose "about to do call a function that does nothing..."
$elapsed = Measure-Command -Expression { do-nothing -foo $myFoo }
Write-Verbose -Verbose "doing nothing took $($elapsed.TotalMilliseconds) milliseconds"
```

Enabling `LogPipelineExecutionDetails` cause large slowdown of function execution. Judging from my digging with ILSpy, logging of pipeline execution details should be enabled only if function belong to module and module enable this option. Maybe that is exact behavior which kb3000850 altering.

It would be interesting to see if problem reproduced when `do-nothing` belong to module, but `LogPipelineExecutionDetails` explicitly set to `$false`.

Answer (score 2):

Supplementary information, posted as an additional community wiki answer to avoid the character limit per answer.

---

As requested by @PetSerAl I ran the following code before and after installing kb3000850:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
public static class C{
  public static System.Collections.IEnumerable M(){
    System.Console.WriteLine(new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace());
    yield break;
  }
}
'@

function do-nothing {
  param($foo)
  Write-Verbose -Verbose "in the function"
}

$myFoo = [C]::M()

Write-Verbose -Verbose "about to do call a function that does nothing..."
$elapsed = Measure-Command -Expression { do-nothing -foo $myFoo }
Write-Verbose -Verbose "doing nothing took $($elapsed.TotalMilliseconds) milliseconds"
```

Stacktrace before update:

```
at C.<M>d__0.MoveNext()
at System.Management.Automation.PSObject.ToStringEnumerable(ExecutionContext context, IEnumerable enumerable, String separator, String format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
at System.Management.Automation.PSObject.ToString(ExecutionContext context, Object obj, String separator, String format, IFormatProvider formatProvider, Boolean recurse, Boolean unravelEnumeratorOnRecurse)
at System.Management.Automation.PSObject.ToStringParser(ExecutionContext context, Object obj)
at System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives.ConvertNonNumericToString(Object valueToConvert, Type resultType, Boolean recursion, PSObject originalValueToConvert, IFormatProvider formatProvider, TypeTable backupTable)
at System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives.ConversionData`1.Invoke(Object valueToConvert, Type resultType, Boolean recurse, PSObject originalValueToConvert, IFormatProvider formatProvider, TypeTable backupTable)
at System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTo(Object valueToConvert, Type resultType, Boolean recursion, IFormatProvider formatProvider, TypeTable backupTypeTable)
at System.Management.Automation.ParameterBinderBase.CoerceTypeAsNeeded(CommandParameterInternal argument, String parameterName, Type toType, ParameterCollectionTypeInformation collectionTypeInfo, Object currentValue)
at System.Management.Automation.ParameterBinderBase.BindParameter(CommandParameterInternal parameter, CompiledCommandParameter parameterMetadata, ParameterBindingFlags flags)
at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindParameter(CommandParameterInternal argument, MergedCompiledCommandParameter parameter, ParameterBindingFlags flags)
at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindParameter(UInt32 parameterSets, CommandParameterInternal argument, MergedCompiledCommandParameter parameter, ParameterBindingFlags flags)
at System.Management.Automation.ParameterBinderController.BindPositionalParametersInSet(UInt32 validParameterSets, Dictionary`2 nextPositionalParameters, CommandParameterInternal argument, ParameterBindingFlags flags, ParameterBindingException& bindingException)
at System.Management.Automation.ParameterBinderController.BindPositionalParameters(Collection`1 unboundArguments, UInt32 validParameterSets, UInt32 defaultParameterSet, ParameterBindingException& outgoingBindingException)
at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindCommandLineParametersNoValidation(Collection`1 arguments)
at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindCommandLineParameters(Collection`1 arguments)
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.BindCommandLineParameters()
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoPrepare(IDictionary psDefaultParameterValues)
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.Start(Boolean incomingStream)
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)
at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)
at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipeImpl(ScriptBlockClauseToInvoke clauseToInvoke, Boolean createLocalScope, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, List`1 variablesToDefine, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Object[] args)
at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeWithPipe>b__8()
at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceBase.RunActionIfNoRunningPipelinesWithThreadCheck(Action action)
at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipe(Boolean useLocalScope, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, List`1 variablesToDefine, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Object[] args)
at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MeasureCommandCommand.ProcessRecord()
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute()
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)
at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)
at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)
at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper()
at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc()
at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc()
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Stacktrace after update (differences highlighted):

```
at C.<M>d__0.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Management.Automation.ParameterBinderBase.BindParameter(CommandParameterInternal parameter, CompiledCommandParameter parameterMetadata, ParameterBindingFlags flags)
at System.Management.Automation.ParameterBinderController.BindParameter(UInt32 parameterSets, CommandParameterInternal argument, MergedCompiledCommandParameter parameter, ParameterBindingFlags flags)
at System.Management.Automation.ScriptParameterBinderController.BindParameters(Collection`1 arguments)
at System.Management.Automation.ScriptParameterBinderController.BindCommandLineParameters(Collection`1 arguments)
at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.EnterScope()
at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)
at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.Complete()
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)
at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipeImpl(ScriptBlockClauseToInvoke clauseToInvoke, Boolean createLocalScope, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, List`1 variablesToDefine, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Object[] args)
at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeWithPipe>b__8()
at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceBase.RunActionIfNoRunningPipelinesWithThreadCheck(Action action)
at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipe(Boolean useLocalScope, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, List`1 variablesToDefine, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Object[] args)
at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MeasureCommandCommand.ProcessRecord()
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute()
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)
at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)
at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.Complete()
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)
at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)
at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.Complete()
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)
at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper()
at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc()
at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc()
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

at C.<M>d__0.MoveNext()
at System.Management.Automation.PSObject.ToStringEnumerable(ExecutionContext context, IEnumerable enumerable, String separator, String format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
at System.Management.Automation.PSObject.ToString(ExecutionContext context, Object obj, String separator, String format, IFormatProvider formatProvider, Boolean recurse, Boolean unravelEnumeratorOnRecurse)
at System.Management.Automation.PSObject.ToStringParser(ExecutionContext context, Object obj)
at System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives.ConvertNonNumericToString(Object valueToConvert, Type resultType, Boolean recursion, PSObject originalValueToConvert, IFormatProvider formatProvider, TypeTable backupTable)
at System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives.ConversionData`1.Invoke(Object valueToConvert, Type resultType, Boolean recurse, PSObject originalValueToConvert, IFormatProvider formatProvider, TypeTable backupTable)
at System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTo(Object valueToConvert, Type resultType, Boolean recursion, IFormatProvider formatProvider, TypeTable backupTypeTable)
at System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTo(Object valueToConvert, Type resultType, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
at System.Management.Automation.ParameterBinderBase.CoerceTypeAsNeeded(CommandParameterInternal argument, String parameterName, Type toType, ParameterCollectionTypeInformation collectionTypeInfo, Object currentValue)
at System.Management.Automation.ParameterBinderBase.BindParameter(CommandParameterInternal parameter, CompiledCommandParameter parameterMetadata, ParameterBindingFlags flags)
at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindParameter(CommandParameterInternal argument, MergedCompiledCommandParameter parameter, ParameterBindingFlags flags)
at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindParameter(UInt32 parameterSets, CommandParameterInternal argument, MergedCompiledCommandParameter parameter, ParameterBindingFlags flags)
at System.Management.Automation.ParameterBinderController.BindPositionalParametersInSet(UInt32 validParameterSets, Dictionary`2 nextPositionalParameters, CommandParameterInternal argument, ParameterBindingFlags flags, ParameterBindingException& bindingException)
at System.Management.Automation.ParameterBinderController.BindPositionalParameters(Collection`1 unboundArguments, UInt32 validParameterSets, UInt32 defaultParameterSet, ParameterBindingException& outgoingBindingException)
at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindCommandLineParametersNoValidation(Collection`1 arguments)
at System.Management.Automation.CmdletParameterBinderController.BindCommandLineParameters(Collection`1 arguments)
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.BindCommandLineParameters()
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoPrepare(IDictionary psDefaultParameterValues)
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.Start(Boolean incomingStream)
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)
at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)
at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.Complete()
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)
at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipeImpl(ScriptBlockClauseToInvoke clauseToInvoke, Boolean createLocalScope, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, List`1 variablesToDefine, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Object[] args)
at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeWithPipe>b__8()
at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceBase.RunActionIfNoRunningPipelinesWithThreadCheck(Action action)
at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipe(Boolean useLocalScope, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, List`1 variablesToDefine, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Object[] args)
at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MeasureCommandCommand.ProcessRecord()
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute()
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)
at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)
at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.Complete()
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)
at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)
at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.Complete()
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)
at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)
at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper()
at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc()
at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc()
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
VERBOSE: about to do call a function that does nothing...
VERBOSE: in the function
VERBOSE: doing nothing took 9345.0445 milliseconds
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ref?view=powershell-7.1#writing-functions-to-accept-reference-parameters

```
function do-nothing
{
    param([ref]$foo)
    # When using references, you must use the Value property of
    # the System.Management.Automation.PSReference type to access your data.
    $foo.Value 
    Write-Verbose -Verbose "in the function"
}

$tenMiB = 10 * 1024 * 1024
$myFoo = New-Object byte[] $tenMiB

Write-Verbose -Verbose "about to do call a function that does nothing..."
$elapsed = Measure-Command -Expression { do-nothing -foo ([ref]$myFoo) }
Write-Verbose -Verbose "doing nothing took $($elapsed.TotalMilliseconds) milliseconds"
```

_

```
VERBOSE: about to do call a function that does nothing...
VERBOSE: in the function
VERBOSE: doing nothing took 1303.8049 milliseconds
```